# Can't upload the theme

Tags: themes, uploads

When I upload a theme on wordpress I get this message
[image]

Since I'm new to WordPress, What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you had upload that theme earlier. Go to Media, then find the item which has the same name of the theme you want to upload. Click it, and delete it. After that upload your theme again.